# material angular sidenav trigger resize

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular9

I'm using angular 8 and material theme. Following https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

I'm generating the content inside `<mat-sidenav> </mat-sidenav>` dynamically by user input.

When I toggle the status, it automatically resizes the content. For example, when I first opened it is like this.

[image: the menu button can be seen]

When I change the content inside the sidenav to a longer content, It DOES NOT resizes.

[image]

Maybe I can trigger it by opening and closing the sidenav. Is there a function to trigger resize?

In the docs I see

> @Input()
>     autosize: boolean 
>   Whether to automatically resize the container whenever the size of any of its drawers changes. Use at **your own risk**! Enabling this option can cause layout thrashing by measuring the drawers on every change detection cycle. Can be configured globally via the MAT_DRAWER_DEFAULT_AUTOSIZE token.

I don't want to use autosize.

note:

```
setTimeout(() => this.isOpen = false, 0);
setTimeout(() => this.isOpen = true, 1);
```

works fine expect for focusing on the menu button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to set autosize to true when you know you are going to change the size of the sidenav and turn it off once the resizing is complete.

```js
autosize: boolean = false;

doSomethingToChangeSidenavWidth() {
  // do something...
  // ...then
  this.autosize = true;
  setTimeout(() => this.autosize = false, 1);
}
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" [(autosize)]="autosize">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already stated that "I don't want to use `autosize`."

Comment: canbax, I interpreted from from your original question that you didn't want to use autosize because of the possibility of "thrashing". Having the autosize property turned off on the next available timeout cycle will prevent any possibility of thrashing. Did you try this and did it solve your problem?

Comment: hm, actually that looks pretty reasonable. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: nice solution to prevent thrashing

Comment: is there a way to make it look nicer the autosizing e.g add animations to it? @SteveC